# Apply jQuery autocomplete to an input field only when it has a certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Bootstrap input element with a dropdown button attached. Search options can be selected from the dropdown menu: search by quote, search by character. When an option is selected, the relevant class is added to the input element and the current class is removed.

I'm trying to apply the autocomplete function to the input field only when it has the class 'character' - when the 'search by character' option has been selected. I don't want the autocomplete list to be displayed when the 'search by quote' option has been selected.

Do I need to trigger the autocomplete function using the click event-handler - when the 'search by character' option s selected?

My **HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Search by <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li id="quoteSearch"><a href="#">quote</a></li>
            <li id="charSearch"><a href="#">character</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input id="searchBox" type="text" class="form-control quote" placeholder="Search by quote" aria-label="...">
</div>
```

My **JS** file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Turn search field into character search
    $("#charSearch").click(function(){
        $("#searchBox").removeAttr("placeholder");
        $("#searchBox").attr("placeholder", "Search by character");
        $("#searchBox").removeClass("quote");
        $("#searchBox").addClass("character");
    });

    // Turn search field into quote search (default)
    $("#quoteSearch").click(function(){
        $("#searchBox").removeAttr("placeholder");
        $("#searchBox").attr("placeholder", "Search by quote");
        $("#searchBox").removeClass("character");
        $("#searchBox").addClass("quote");
    });

    // Autocomplete for character search
    $(function(){
        var availableTags = ['One' , 'Two' , 'Three' , 'Four']

        $(".character").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the autocomplete method to the input, and unbind it when the other search type is selected:

```
var availableTags = ['One' , 'Two' , 'Three' , 'Four']

$("#charSearch").click(function(){
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
    });
});

$("#quoteSearch").click(function(){
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete("destroy");
    $("#searchBox").removeData('autocomplete');
});
```